# Examples of computing Ext and Tor functors?

Tags: homological-algebra, cohomology

So I understand in theory the definition of Ext and Tor, but when it comes to actually computing them, I'm stuck.  For example, could someone show me how to compute $\text{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$?  I tried this by taking an injective resolution ($0 \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to 0$?) and I got an exact sequence with $\text{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) = 0$, but I don't see what to do next?

P.S. No, this is not a homework question.

Comment: Use a *projective* resolution.

Comment: of the other one, of course!

Comment: Ext(Z/mZ,Z/nZ) is the quotient of Hom(Z/nZ,Q/Z) by the image of multiplication by m from Hom(Z/nZ,Q/Z).  Hom(Z/nZ,Q/Z) is equal to Hom(Z/nZ,Z/nZ) since an element of order n must go to an element of order n in Q/Z.  If you'd like, Z/nZ can be rewritten as (1/n)Z / Z ≤ Q/Z.  Hom(Z/nZ,Z/nZ) is the ring Z/nZ and multiplication of m has image (mZ+nZ)/(nZ) = gcd(m,n)Z/nZ, so the quotient is Z/gcd(m,n)Z.  In other words, Ext(Z/mZ,Z/nZ) = Z/gcd(m,n)Z.  If m,n are coprime, this is Z/Z = 0.  Hom, tensor, Ext and Tor are somewhat silly on finitely generated abelian groups, so you might try other groups.

Comment: @adeel: have you consulted an arbitrary introduction to homological algebra?

Comment: Exceptionally, I don't think the downvote is right here...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a pretty terrible abelian group, or a rather hard one, there may be better injective resolutions to work with. It would certainly be easier to do the projective resolution, use $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n \to 0$. this will surely be easier to work through than the one involving $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Then compute the appropriate tensor product or hom group.

I started learning this stuff on more interesting modules as Schmidt suggests. For example, modules over the group ring of some cyclic group, or maybe an exterior algebra on two generators (if you make the generators of different gradings, in particular 1 and 3). This happens to be the category of modules you need to understand in order to compute complex connective k-theory!

this should help get you going. These computations are very fun!